# css transform via jQuery is not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, css

I'm trying to move an horizontal list when you hover over the li elements. The animation involves some showing/hiding & resizing of new divs and a X translation for the ul. Everyting works fine except the X translation on firefox.

The actual script is to big to be posted on Jsfiddle but here is the "troublemaker"

The JS code is :

```
var translation="translateX("+next_move+"px)";
console.log("translation: "+translation);
$('#carousel').css({"top":"10px","-moz-transform":translation});
$('#carousel').css({"top":"10px","-webkit-transform":translation});
```

the CSS for `#carousel`

```
#carousel{
    position:relative;
    webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s linear; 
   -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.2s linear;  
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.2s linear;  
    transition: transform 0.2s linear; 
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction ?
thanks

Comment: What if you use this
`$('#carousel').css({"top":"10px !important","-moz-transform":'translation !important'});`
Does it make any change?

Comment: no change,Thanks for the ideea

Comment: What if you make a new CSS class and use 'addClass' method of jquery to add that class to your required area?

Comment: the "size" of transition depends of a variable and it doesn't have a fixed size. Can be -200 or -243. The value is calculated before reaching this moment.